# Using mod_rewrite to redirect unsupported language codes

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a multilingual site, and I'm using language identifiers in urls in conjunction with a front controller such that visiting

```
http://www.domain.tld/en/content
```

or

```
http://www.domain.tld/de/conent
```

will pull up content localised in those languages. If the site is visited without specifying a language identifier, the users browsers language settings are detected via Accept-Language as a best guess, and then redirected. If Accept-Language cannot be detected, then it defaults to english. So, for example, if you visit

```
http://www.domain.tld/content
```

and your browsers language settings are in german and Accept-Language detects de, you'll be redirected to

```
http://www.domain.tld/de/content
```

If your browsers language settings are not supported, you'll be redirected to the default supported language, english

```
http://www.domain.tld/en/content
```

This works fine... as long as don't manually put in a url with an unsupported language identifier at the beginning of the url. To explain, I have mod_rewrite set up such that urls that dont point to existing files or folders invoke the front controller. That being the case, if I purposefully put in an unsupported language code in the browser, such as 'it',

```
http://www.domain.tld/it/content
```

The front controller is invoked, but I want to avoid this, instead prefering to have Apache filter requests such that only supported languages are provided to the front controller.

Essentially what I want is to be able to define a rule such that if a url does not start with a supported language identifier, that users will abe redirected to a url that replaces the unsupported language code with the default one (en) without invoking the front controller.

This is my config file:

```
# 
#   Access rights and behaviours for DocumentRoot
#       
<Directory /WWW>
    # 
    Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes -MultiViews

    # Allow requests for all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    # Don't use access rules defined in child directories
    AllowOverride None 

    # Define the router as the default index page
    DirectoryIndex /router.php

    # Turn on url rewriting
    RewriteEngine on    

    # If we encounter a request to document root and can detect a language preference, grab it...
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(en|de|fr)[-,;]? [NC,OR]
    # ... or use the default language identifier (english) ...
    RewriteCond en ^(en)$
    # ... and redirect the request to a path prefixed with the language identifier
    RewriteRule ^$ /%1/ [R=301,L]


            # Mystery rule here!


    # If the requested file does not exist...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # ... or if the requested directory does not exist
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # ...forward the request to the router
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php/$1 [L]        
</Directory>
```

Where I've put the "Mystery rule here!" comment is where I need to define a rule such that if the request uri does not begin with a supported language code, that en will be used in place.

I've tried doing this a number of ways, but keep falling into redirect loops. To example what I'm trying to do

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|de|fr).$
RewriteRule ^$ /en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What this is supposed to represent is:

If the request uri does not begin with en, de or fr, grab the remainder of the uri, prefix it with en, then redirect for the front controller to intercept.

Can anyone advise me? Thanks!

Comment: I think that if you add [L], it means that no rules will be accepted afterward. So you can case your redirection rules, and put a final one:

# no one has matched, execute this one
RewriteRule .*$ /en/unsupported.html [L]

but this is only an idea.

Comment: Doesn’t your router/application handle these cases? I mean, it should know best what languages are present. By the way, just looking if a specific language is mentioned in *Accept-Language* is not a good way. Because *Accept-Language* is a list of weighted values and the first value doesn’t have to be the preferred one. In fact, a quality value of 0 (`q=0`) means *not acceptable at all*.

Comment: @Gumbo- Thanks for the heads up on Accept-Language.Thats a hack on my behalf- I was previously using content negotiation, which factors in the weightings I believe. 

There is zero problem having the front controller deal with the issue, its just that I want Apache and mod-rewrite to preprocess and filter routed uris - I want to avoid waking up PHP as much as possible.

I really should reduce the problem: how can I instruct mod_rewrite to ensure that the first path component of a uri is acceptable, and do nothing, or else replace an unacceptable component with an acceptable one, then redirect?

Comment: Again, I wouldn’t choose a language without proper negotiation. Even the default language should only be chosen if negotiation fails and not just because there was no language explicitly chosen. So why don’t you use a lightweight PHP script (or whatever other language you might prefer) to do a proper language negotiation?

Comment: @Gumbo- I appreciate your feedback, but this question is not about content negotiation, or how to best implement it- thats a huge area, the question is about filtering urls before hitting the front controller. If it helps, just the consider above as a use case for mod_rewrite in that capacity for development purposes, and not production.

Answer (score 2):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule !^(en|de|fr)/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This will add `/en` at the begin of the URI path if it does not already start with either `/en`, `/de`, or `/fr`.